# Marketing Cloud: Update Contact Opt In Status via Import Definition

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

Is there a way to update the mobile connect contact's status from Not Opted in to Opted in via Import Mobile Contact List definition or Query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not using Import or query. But you can do that using SOAP API

Comment: Thanks @maneesh. We just tried this using rest and it works!